# Process post action with another action within controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have a terribly designed app where the `index` action displays a form in a JavaScript-based dialogue that's submitted to `process` action and then redirects to `index` (either on success or on error). The `process` action does not even have a view:

```
class UnicornsController
{
    public function index($foo, $bar)
    {
        $this->set(
            array(
                'unicorn' => $this->Unicorn->findByFooAndBar($foo, $bar);
            )
        );
    }

    public function process()
    {
        $this->Unicorn->save($this->request->data);
        $this->redirect(
            array(
                'action' => 'index',
                $this->request->data['Unicorn']['foo'],
                $this->request->data['Unicorn']['bar'],
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I'm adding proper error reporting. I'm trying to change the `this->redirect()` part so `$this->request->data` is not lost and I have a chance to display it again in the form generated in `index.ctp` but I can't get it right: both `$this->requestAction()` and `$this->index()` try to render `process.ctp` anyway. Am I using them incorrectly or I'm missing the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a different action, you can use `Controller::setAction()`, it changes the `action` parameter in the request, sets the template to render accordingly, and returns the possible return value of the invoked action.

```
public function process()
{
    // ....

    $this->setAction(
        'index',
        $this->request->data['Unicorn']['foo'],
        $this->request->data['Unicorn']['bar']
    );
}
```

See also

- **[API > Controller::setAction()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/class-Controller.html#_setAction)**